# GlusterFS v3.10 not mounting on boot Centos 7.3-1611

Tags: linux, glusterfs

*FIXED* for me at least. And I have no idea how. I've run through the logs from when it wasn't working to now when it is and I cannot for the life of my see any different. What is different and I don't know if it's a coincidence is when I execute

`gluster volume status`

On both nodes they both say `Task Status of Volume glustervol1` where as before in server2 it was the hostname of the box. I have no idea how that happened. But it did... Don't know if that fixed it or what but it did it on it's own after numerous reboots.

### Good luck.

STILL?! There's a lot of writing on this from 2014 ish on ubuntu and 14.04 using init. I'm running `centos 7.3-1611` fully patched with kernel `3.10.0-514.10.2.el7`, and gluster volumes still don't mount after reboot on servers where the lvm bricks and the client vol mount are on the same server.

I have 3 boxes

- server1  (server peer1) and client
- server2: (server peer2) and client
- server3: client only

They are using lvm backend. And the glustervol should mount to /data/glusterfs. The issue isn't present on server3 where it's only a client. It connects and mounts using the same rules as the other servers. I've dug into the data logs, into selinux into the start up log. I can't find a way around it. I've considered CTBD and tried autofs to no avail.

#### gluster version

`glusterfs 3.10.0
Repository revision: git://git.gluster.org/glusterfs.git
Copyright (c) 2006-2016 Red Hat, Inc. <https://www.gluster.org/>
GlusterFS comes with ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY.
It is licensed to you under your choice of the GNU Lesser
General Public License, version 3 or any later version (LGPLv3
or later), or the GNU General Public License, version 2 (GPLv2),
in all cases as published by the Free Software Foundation.`

#### fstab

`/dev/vg_gluster/brick1  /data/bricks/brick1  xfs        defaults         0 0
gluster1:/glustervol1   /data/glusterfs      glusterfs  defaults,_netdev 0 0`

What's expected

`sdb                 LVM2_member       6QrvQI-v5L9-bds3-BUn0-ySdB-hDmz-nVojpX
└─vg_gluster-brick1 xfs               d181747c-8ed3-430c-bd1c-0b7968666dfe   /data/bricks/brick1
 and
gluster1:/glustervol1           49G   33M   49G   1% /data/glusterfs`

This works by running the manual `mount -t glusterfs...` or by executing `mount -a` with the rules in my `fstab`. But it will not work on boot. I've read that it's something to do with the mounts trying to happen before the daemon started. What is the best workaround for this? Is it to edit systemd files? Does anyone know a fix?

This is a snippet of a fresh boot while trying to mount through fstab where it's saying that there is no brick process running.

`[2017-04-03 16:35:47.353523] I [MSGID: 100030] [glusterfsd.c:2460:main] 0-/usr/sbin/glusterfs: Started running /usr/sbin/glusterfs version 3.10.0 (args: /usr/sbin/glusterfs --volfile-server=gluster1 --volfile-id=/glustervol1 /data/glusterfs)
[2017-04-03 16:35:47.456915] I [MSGID: 101190] [event-epoll.c:629:event_dispatch_epoll_worker] 0-epoll: Started thread with index 1
[2017-04-03 16:35:48.711381] I [afr.c:94:fix_quorum_options] 0-glustervol1-replicate-0: reindeer: incoming qtype = none
[2017-04-03 16:35:48.711398] I [afr.c:116:fix_quorum_options] 0-glustervol1-replicate-0: reindeer: quorum_count = 0
[2017-04-03 16:35:48.712437] I [socket.c:4120:socket_init] 0-glustervol1-client-1: SSL support on the I/O path is ENABLED
[2017-04-03 16:35:48.712451] I [socket.c:4140:socket_init] 0-glustervol1-client-1: using private polling thread
[2017-04-03 16:35:48.712892] E [socket.c:4201:socket_init] 0-glustervol1-client-1: failed to open /etc/ssl/dhparam.pem, DH ciphers are disabled
[2017-04-03 16:35:48.713139] I [MSGID: 101190] [event-epoll.c:629:event_dispatch_epoll_worker] 0-epoll: Started thread with index 2
[2017-04-03 16:35:48.759228] I [socket.c:4120:socket_init] 0-glustervol1-client-0: SSL support on the I/O path is ENABLED
[2017-04-03 16:35:48.759243] I [socket.c:4140:socket_init] 0-glustervol1-client-0: using private polling thread
[2017-04-03 16:35:48.759308] E [socket.c:4201:socket_init] 0-glustervol1-client-0: failed to open /etc/ssl/dhparam.pem, DH ciphers are disabled
[2017-04-03 16:35:48.759596] W [MSGID: 101174] [graph.c:361:_log_if_unknown_option] 0-glustervol1-readdir-ahead: option 'parallel-readdir' is not recognized
[2017-04-03 16:35:48.759680] I [MSGID: 114020] [client.c:2352:notify] 0-glustervol1-client-0: parent translators are ready, attempting connect on transport
[2017-04-03 16:35:48.762408] I [MSGID: 114020] [client.c:2352:notify] 0-glustervol1-client-1: parent translators are ready, attempting connect on transport
[2017-04-03 16:35:48.904234] E [MSGID: 114058] [client-handshake.c:1538:client_query_portmap_cbk] 0-glustervol1-client-0: failed to get the port number for remote subvolume. Please run 'gluster volume status' on server to see if brick process is running.
[2017-04-03 16:35:48.904286] I [MSGID: 114018] [client.c:2276:client_rpc_notify] 0-glustervol1-client-0: disconnected from glustervol1-client-0. Client process will keep trying to connect to glusterd until brick's port is available
Final graph:
+------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
  1: volume glustervol1-client-0
  2:     type protocol/client
  3:     option ping-timeout 42
  4:     option remote-host gluster1
  5:     option remote-subvolume /data/bricks/brick1/brick
  6:     option transport-type socket
  7:     option transport.address-family inet
  8:     option username xxx
  9:     option password xxx
 10:     option transport.socket.ssl-enabled on
 11:     option send-gids true
 12: end-volume
 13:
 14: volume glustervol1-client-1
 15:     type protocol/client
 16:     option ping-timeout 42
 17:     option remote-host gluster2
 18:     option remote-subvolume /data/bricks/brick1/brick
 19:     option transport-type socket
 20:     option transport.address-family inet
 21:     option username xxx
 22:     option password xxx
 23:     option transport.socket.ssl-enabled on
 24:     option send-gids true
 25: end-volume
 26:
 27: volume glustervol1-replicate-0
 28:     type cluster/replicate
 29:     option afr-pending-xattr glustervol1-client-0,glustervol1-client-1
 30:     option use-compound-fops off
 31:     subvolumes glustervol1-client-0 glustervol1-client-1
 32: end-volume
 33:
 34: volume glustervol1-dht
 35:     type cluster/distribute
 36:     option lock-migration off
 37:     subvolumes glustervol1-replicate-0
 38: end-volume
 39:
 40: volume glustervol1-write-behind
 41:     type performance/write-behind
 42:     subvolumes glustervol1-dht
 43: end-volume
 44:
 45: volume glustervol1-read-ahead
 46:     type performance/read-ahead
 47:     subvolumes glustervol1-write-behind
 48: end-volume
 49:
 50: volume glustervol1-readdir-ahead
 51:     type performance/readdir-ahead
 52:     option parallel-readdir off
 53:     option rda-request-size 131072
 54:     option rda-cache-limit 10MB
 55:     subvolumes glustervol1-read-ahead
 56: end-volume
 57:
 58: volume glustervol1-io-cache
 59:     type performance/io-cache
 60:     subvolumes glustervol1-readdir-ahead
 61: end-volume
 62:
 63: volume glustervol1-quick-read
 64:     type performance/quick-read
 65:     subvolumes glustervol1-io-cache
 66: end-volume
 67:
 68: volume glustervol1-open-behind
 69:     type performance/open-behind
 70:     subvolumes glustervol1-quick-read
 71: end-volume
 72:
 73: volume glustervol1-md-cache
 74:     type performance/md-cache
 75:     subvolumes glustervol1-open-behind
 76: end-volume
 77:
 78: volume glustervol1
 79:     type debug/io-stats
 80:     option log-level INFO
 81:     option latency-measurement off
 82:     option count-fop-hits off
 83:     subvolumes glustervol1-md-cache
 84: end-volume
 85:
 86: volume meta-autoload
 87:     type meta
 88:     subvolumes glustervol1
 89: end-volume
 90:
+------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
[2017-04-03 16:35:48.949500] I [rpc-clnt.c:1964:rpc_clnt_reconfig] 0-glustervol1-client-1: changing port to 49152 (from 0)
[2017-04-03 16:35:49.105087] I [socket.c:348:ssl_setup_connection] 0-glustervol1-client-1: peer CN = <name>
[2017-04-03 16:35:49.105103] I [socket.c:351:ssl_setup_connection] 0-glustervol1-client-1: SSL verification succeeded (client: <ip>:24007)
[2017-04-03 16:35:49.106999] I [MSGID: 114057] [client-handshake.c:1451:select_server_supported_programs] 0-glustervol1-client-1: Using Program GlusterFS 3.3, Num (1298437), Version (330)
[2017-04-03 16:35:49.109591] I [MSGID: 114046] [client-handshake.c:1216:client_setvolume_cbk] 0-glustervol1-client-1: Connected to glustervol1-client-1, attached to remote volume '/data/bricks/brick1/brick'.
[2017-04-03 16:35:49.109609] I [MSGID: 114047] [client-handshake.c:1227:client_setvolume_cbk] 0-glustervol1-client-1: Server and Client lk-version numbers are not same, reopening the fds
[2017-04-03 16:35:49.109713] I [MSGID: 108005] [afr-common.c:4756:afr_notify] 0-glustervol1-replicate-0: Subvolume 'glustervol1-client-1' came back up; going online.
[2017-04-03 16:35:49.110987] I [fuse-bridge.c:4146:fuse_init] 0-glusterfs-fuse: FUSE inited with protocol versions: glusterfs 7.24 kernel 7.22
[2017-04-03 16:35:49.111004] I [fuse-bridge.c:4831:fuse_graph_sync] 0-fuse: switched to graph 0
[2017-04-03 16:35:49.112283] I [MSGID: 114035] [client-handshake.c:202:client_set_lk_version_cbk] 0-glustervol1-client-1: Server lk version = 1
[2017-04-03 16:35:52.547781] I [rpc-clnt.c:1964:rpc_clnt_reconfig] 0-glustervol1-client-0: changing port to 49152 (from 0)
[2017-04-03 16:35:52.558003] I [socket.c:348:ssl_setup_connection] 0-glustervol1-client-0: peer CN = <name>
[2017-04-03 16:35:52.558015] I [socket.c:351:ssl_setup_connection] 0-glustervol1-client-0: SSL verification succeeded (client: <ip>:24007)
[2017-04-03 16:35:52.558167] I [MSGID: 114057] [client-handshake.c:1451:select_server_supported_programs] 0-glustervol1-client-0: Using Program GlusterFS 3.3, Num (1298437), Version (330)
[2017-04-03 16:35:52.558592] I [MSGID: 114046] [client-handshake.c:1216:client_setvolume_cbk] 0-glustervol1-client-0: Connected to glustervol1-client-0, attached to remote volume '/data/bricks/brick1/brick'.
[2017-04-03 16:35:52.558604] I [MSGID: 114047] [client-handshake.c:1227:client_setvolume_cbk] 0-glustervol1-client-0: Server and Client lk-version numbers are not same, reopening the fds
[2017-04-03 16:35:52.558781] I [MSGID: 114035] [client-handshake.c:202:client_set_lk_version_cbk] 0-glustervol1-client-0: Server lk version = 1`

Comment: This has literally just fixed itself... after 5 hours so hair pulling now they mount on reboot. I changed nothing. FML.

Comment: ^ LOL Seriously, though I've had this same issue when using server nodes as clients. It's a race condition, and the fstab is pretty stupid. I solved the issue by creating a systemd unit file for mounting glusterfs via FUSE that called a dependency on the volume daemon being started first.

Comment: One could also get away with using the automounter for this. In fact, since it's a network filesystem, you probably should be using autofs.

Comment: The initial idea was "does it work" after all this trouble It feels a bit sketchy for our production use case. We have Ceph, but to get this in place took less than an hour and then a few more of me screaming profanities.

Answer (score 1):

#### 1st post the recommended solution

Perhaps you could try

`ip:/volume /dir glusterfs defaults,noauto,x-systemd.automount,x-systemd.device-timeout=30,_netdev 0 0`.

*refer [archwiki-fstab#remote filesystem](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Fstab#Remote_filesystem)*

Beacuse my OS is Cent6.9 without systemd, so it does not work for me.(maybe there are some options for init, please tell me if you know :) )

#### 2nd problem description

I had added rule in `fstab`, but glusterfs could not be automatically mounted after booted. Ver 3.10.

I execute command `mount -a`, the filesystem could be mounted.

Saw log file `/etc/log/boot.log`, it find that filesystem was mounted failed.

Saw log file `/var/log/gluster/<your gluster volume name>.log`, it said that connected gluster server failed (but ping server, it is fine).

**I think that maybe network was not ready while mounting?**

#### 3th my inelegant solution

I search many issues, blogs or forums, the problem was not be solved...

In the end, I given up , and added a command in `/etc/rc.local`

```
sleep 30s
mount -a
```

This solution is ugly(maybe), but the world will be beautiful again after system reboot.

Answer (score -1):

```
#gluster volume set glustervol1 performance.cache-size 32MB
```

set your read cache low memory

Comment: this needs a lot more details.